# Count number of occcurance of a field for each ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Consider a table consisting of two columns: `device_id, connection_type` like:

```
device_id  | connection_types 
-----------|------------------
111        |   wifi           
111        |   LTE   
222        |   wifi           
111        |   LTE 
111        |   LTE          
111        |   cable
....
```

For each device, I want to get values of field `connection_type` along with number of their appearances. For example two rows for output will look like:

```
device_id  | connection_types | connection_count
-----------|------------------|-------------------
111        |   wifi           | 3
           |   LTE            | 5
           |   cable          | 2
-----------|------------------|-------------------
222        |  wifi            | 4
           |  cable           | 6
```

Indicating that device 111, is connected with wifi in 3 rows,
LTE in 5 and cable in 2 of rows it appears. 
How can I calculate this using SQL in Google BigQuery (using either its legacy SQL or standard SQL dialect).

It is good to point out that (as also suggested by @kbball) grouping by both `device_id`, `connection_type` does something similar but I cant convert that output to the sample answer I provided above.

I've considered using  `nest()` or `array_agg()` but none of them works. I can't use `nest()` simultaneously on both of columns `connection_types` and `connection_count`. and because there is no data for some devices, `array_agg()` 
results in error (that its output can not be empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get for every device id an array of (connection_types, connection_count) pairs, the following query in Standard SQL will do it:

```
SELECT device_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(connection_types, connection_count)) FROM (
SELECT device_id, connection_types, COUNT(*) connection_count
FROM t
GROUP BY device_id, connection_types) 
GROUP BY device_id
```

Comment: I know this was not part of my question, but can you  suggest a way to do this if there is more than just one filed (for example there is also `device_county`) other than running the query for each one and joining the results

Comment: I think this would work naturally if you add more fields into both inner GROUP BY and STRUCT inside ARRAY_AGG, but if you were to update your question, or to post new question with clear examples of input and output - it would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this although the device id will repeat for each line:

```
SELECT device_id, connection_types, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY device_id, connection_types
ORDER BY device_id ASC
```

Comment: I edited my question describing why I wasn't able to use grouping on both fields.